# IndexError: list index out of range for an Array in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to validate that line 12 exists within thousands of lines of data. I am needing to Loop over lines and store the words as a list in file_data and each line we want to split on the ' ' or space so we can divide the them into an array of words.

```
file_data = []

with open('/dsa/data/all_datasets/hamilton-federalist-548.txt', 'r') as file:

# Each line we want to split on the ' ' or space so we can divide the them into an array of words

    for line in file:
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        print(split_line)
        
# ------------ =================== --------------
# just checking a sample line
print(file_data[12])
```

### I am getting this error:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
20 # ------------ =================== --------------
21 # just checking a sample line
---> 22 print(file_data[12])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You aren't appending anything to your `file_data` list

Comment: You never populate `file_data` with anything. It's an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The error **list index out of range** arises if you access invalid indices in your Python list. For example, if you try to access the list element with index 100 but your lists consist only of three elements, Python will throw an IndexError telling you that the list index is out of range.

```
lst = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carl']
print(lst[3])//This will lead to same exception.
```

In your case you haven't inserted any data in file_data variable. Append it and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Your file_data is empty. Maybe this code works for you.

```
file_data = []
    
    
with open('/dsa/data/all_datasets/hamilton-federalist-548.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.readlines()
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        file_data.append(split_line)
        # print(split_line)
            
print(file_data[12])
```

Comment: This worked quite well, now when I run it my conditions are true and I am printing what I need!